# Confirm jQuery executando 2 vezes

Tags: jquery, ajax

Olá, tenho um código que "ativa e desativa" usuários. Este:

HTML

```
 <button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-circle ativar-gestor'>
    <i class='fa fa-check'></i>
    <input type='hidden' value='{$dados['Id']}' name='id'>
 </button>

 <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-circle desativar-gestor'>
    <i class='fa fa-ban'></i>
    <input type='hidden' value='{$dados['Id']}' name='id'>
 </button>
```

jQuery e Ajax (confirmaAtiv executa 2 vezes, mostra a janela de confirmar 2 vezes)

```
//Ativar
$( ".ativar-gestor" ).click(function() {
    var icone        = $(this);
    var id           = $('input', icone).val();
    var confirmaAtiv = confirm('Deseja realmente ativar este gestor?');
    if(confirmaAtiv){
        $.ajax({
            type    : 'POST',
            url     : 'dados/ativar-gestor.php',
            data    : {id : id},
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data){
                if(data.status == 1 || data.status == 2){
                    alert(data.msg);
                    window.location.href="index.php?pg=gestores";
                }else{
                    form.get(0).reset();
                    alert(data.msg);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});

//Desativar
$( ".desativar-gestor" ).click(function() {
    var icone    = $(this);
    var id       = $('input', icone).val();
    var confirmaDesat = confirm('Deseja realmente desativar este gestor?');
    if(confirmaDesat){
        $.ajax({
            type    : 'POST',
            url     : 'dados/desativar-gestor.php',
            data    : {id : id},
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data){
                if(data.status == 1 || data.status == 2){
                    alert(data.msg);
                    window.location.href="index.php?pg=gestores";
                }else{
                    form.get(0).reset();
                    alert(data.msg);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

PHP Ativa Gestor (funciona corretamente)

```
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['id']);

    //Checa existencia do ID
    $sqlCheck = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT Id FROM Gestores WHERE Id = {$id}");


    //Ativa
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sqlCheck) == 1){
        if(mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE Gestores SET Ativo = 1 WHERE Id = {$id}")){
            $retorno = array("status" => 1, "msg" => "Cadastro ativado com sucesso!");
            echo json_encode($retorno);
            exit;
        }else{
            $retorno = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Ocorreu um erro ao ativar o cadastro. Tente novamente.");
            echo json_encode($retorno);
            exit;
        }
    }else{
        $retorno = array("status" => 2, "msg" => "Cadastro inexistente. O que está tentando fazer?");
        echo json_encode($retorno);
        exit;
    }
```

O desativar funciona certinho. O ativar executa correto porém exibe duas vezes a caixa de diálogo pra confirmar. O que estaria errado no código?

Comment: Qual é o código do "confirm"?

Comment: var confirmaAtiv = confirm('Deseja realmente ativar este gestor?');
    if(confirmaAtiv){ (...)

Comment: Estou falando do código da função "confirm".

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta.

Comment: Você esta utilizando a função "confirm", para aparecer para o usuário a mensagem, o problema pode esta nesta função, você poderia editar a pergunta e colocar o código da função "confirm".

Comment: Fiz um teste aqui, e a mensagem só apareceu uma vez, você não tem outro elemento na sua tela com a classe "ativar-gestor", você já tentou usar id.

Comment: com id funciona, mas como eu tenho varias linhas com esse mesmo botão, não seria correto utilizar id... não?

Comment: É verdade, colocar vários botões com o mesmo id não pode, aparentemente seu código esta certinho, tenta fazer o seguinte, var confirmaAtiv = confirm('Deseja realmente ativar este gestor?' + id);, assim você vai saber os id que estão ativando o evento click, assim você vai saber pelo menos quais o botões estão ativando o evento quando você clica.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77533/discussion-between-wictor-chaves-and-aryana-valcanaia).

Comment: @WictorChaves obrigada pela disponibilidade! Acabei esquecendo de retornar aqui. Na verdade não há erros no código de fato. Não consegui sequer encontrar o conflito hahaha, alterei nome de class e nada. A solução foi isolar o código de outros que estavam sendo chamados na página. Agora está ok.